# How to extract a string from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm new to Python without any programming background except for some shell scripting.

I want to extract 2 fields from the below list: Here I want 'title' and 'plays' and assign it to a another list eg) new_list=[title,plays]

```
alist=[(0, 'title', 'TEXT', 0, None, 0), (1, 'plays', 'integer', 0, None, 0)]
```

Comment: is the data you want always in the second position of the tuple?

Comment: Is `new_list = [x[1] for x in alist]` what you want?

Comment: You should use a dictionary. `dict = {"title": [0, "TEXT", 0, None, 0], "plays": [1, "plays", "integer", 0, None, 0]}` now when you go to get a value you can do, `dict['text']` and it will return `[0, 'TEXT', 0, None, 0]`.

Comment: "*I'm new to Python*" - May I suggest that you suspend your current project and first read and work through [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). I promise it will be worth your time.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way, of course, it is just write the assignment statement:

```
new_list=['title','plays']
```

But you probably intended to ask a more general question, like "How can I extract the 2nd item from the first two tuples in a list?" Like so:

```
new_list = [alist[0][1], alist[1][1]]
```

Or maybe you meant, "How can I extract the 2nd item from each tuple in a list?" Like so:

```
new_list = [t[1] for t in alist]
```

Comment: _"The simplest way, of course, it is just write the assignment statement:"_ - You knew exactly what he meant ;) Trying to be funny, eh?

Answer (score 2):

```
alist = [(0, 'title', 'TEXT', 0, None, 0),(0, 'plays', 'integer', 0, None, 0)]
new_list = [alist[0][1], alist[1][1]]
```

to check,

```
print(new_list)
```

**Explain**

This line:

```
alist = [(0, 'title', 'TEXT', 0, None, 0), (0, 'plays', 'integer', 0, None, 0)]
```

Above is actually a `tuple` inside `list`. So inside the the `alist`, there are two `tuples`. Inside each `tuple`, there are `6` `objects`.

So `alist[0]` means, you are calling the first `tuple` inside the `alist`.
and `alist[0][1]` means your are calling `second` element of the first `tuple`. Like this, you can think about `alist[1][1]` also.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry thanx for the information.removed it. :)

Comment: Your welcome ;) I don't no why, but if you don't put a space between `#` and one's comment, Stack Overflow will not recognize it as comment. I'm considering bring this bug up on meta.

Comment: thats better. I never monitored it. anyway thanx and good luck.